# Inflectional forms of verbs using DBsight lucene?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, synonym, lemmatization

I know dbsight allows synonyms and stop words for searching but does this take care of inflectional forms of a verb too e.g. for 'swim' it should find swim, swims, swimming, swam, and swum

Link on DBSight Wiki : http://wiki.dbsight.com/index.php?title=User_dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene comes with a stemmer called "Lucene SnowBall stemmer' (http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/contrib-snowball/index.html). Turns out that DBsight is exposing it as analyzers named SnowBall - *[Language]* e.g SnowBall - English, SnowBall - French etc..

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are looking for can be implemented using [lemmatization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation). I am unaware of an existing Lucene analyzer that does this. [Basis Tech's Lucene package](http://www.basistech.com/lucene/) does lemmatization, but is not free, and I do not know whether it works with dbsight.

Comment: Thanks Yuval for pointing this out. Reading the lemmatization wiki, it seems like a stemmer would work too for me. They actually have link for Lucene Snowball Stemmer (http://e-mats.org/2009/05/modifying-a-lucene-snowball-stemmer/) but I'm not sure how that'll work with DBsight

Comment: My Bad :) I just found the answer to my question at  http://www.dbsight.net/index.php?q=node/395

Seems like DBsight comes with analyzers as Snowball-English ( Snowball-Language)

Comment: Note that stemming != lemmatization. A stemmer may convert 'swimming' into 'swim' but not 'swam' into 'swim'.

Comment: Yep you're right, they're not equal. In the first step, I plan on using stemming and see if it takes care of most searches. If not then definitely I'll look into lemmatization solutions.